# If URL Contains a Specific Port Redirect With JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to redirect a url such as *http://forum.domain.com:4567*
to *https://forum.domain.com*. The code will be run site wide, so it must only redirect when a visitor goes to *http://forum.domain.com:4567*

I have tried this, but it loops:

```
<script>
    if (window.location.href = "http://forum.domain.com:4567") {
        window.location = "https://forum.domain.com";   
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) is a [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) type, which is similar to the [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL) type, meaning it should have a [`port`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/port) property.

You can do something like:

```
if (window.location.port === "4567"){
    window.location = "https://forum.domain.com";
}
```

or in case you want a little more extensibility:

```
if (window.location.port === "4567"){
    window.location = window.location.href.replace(':' + window.location.port, "");
}
```

Comment: This is slightly incorrect. `window.location` does not return the experimental `URL` type. It returns a `Location` type, which is different. This is clearly stated in the linked docs. And the [`port` property of a Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/port) is just a string (as used in your example), not the `Port` object which you link to.

Answer (score 2):

You're `if` check is setting the value, not doing a comparison which is why you get a loop.

Change to:

```
if (window.location.href == "http://forum.domain.com:4567") {
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `==` for comparison.

```
if (window.location.href == "http://forum.domain.com:4567") {
    window.location = "https://forum.domain.com";   
}
```

Single `=` is used for assignment. The code you have doesn't fail because the assignment works, and then `window.location.href` is a truthy value.